# mysql internal relation not working when i export to anther database

Tags: mysql

hi im using mysql database everything working so good so far ..
and i have internal relations like this picture .. 
[image]

but if i export the databsae and import it on new database the internal relations gone like this picture .. 
[image]

so how can i export the database with internal relations .. 
thanks ..

Comment: Could you explain which tool you are using for your backup? mysqldump activates it automatically. But you have to know, that restoring databases with constraints can fail, so that it might be necessary to disble constraints and triggers.

Comment: This looks like phpadmin?  If you want to actually use a good program to do this, download MySQL Workbench and use it from here --> https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/

Comment: NOTE - the only reasonable use for phpadmin is if you are REQUIRED due to web host limitations such as Go Daddy's PLESK packages.  Otherwise, USE WORKBENCH instead as a rule of thumb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe internal relationships are used for the DB Designer, in order to visually draw links between your tables keys. The only way to export those relationships from PhpMyAdmin DB Designer is via PDF, so it is not aimed at importing the structure in another instance.

If you need to have PRIMARY keys and FOREIGN keys, you need to integrate them in your CREATE TABLE directives, like so:

```
CREATE TABLE accounts (
    id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    account_menu_detale_main_account_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(id),
    FOREIGN KEY(account_menu_detale_main_account_id) REFERENCES accounts(id)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Second the accepted answer but wanted to add (although it may be obvious to some) that you must ensure that your data types and lengths are exactly the same in both tables for the columns/keys being referenced otherwise it will not work.

Comment: Oh, well then comment on his answer , this is not also an answer.

Comment: Don't have enough reputation to comment on his answer and just wanted to be helpful.

Comment: that is the irony, this is how you lose it, it is why i was warning you, i personally don't care, but I know there are people addicted to getting rep and the easiest way to gain it is flagging things like this :(